# How to show result in textbox?

Tags: asp.net

In my form,there is one textbox for showing productname.I want like this when type l in textbox,it show all record start from l as suggestion.
I writing query and executing the same for selecting productname from table where productname like 'l%'.In asp.net textbox does not contain onblur event or focus event.In which event,shall I execute query.I tried on textbox_textchange event.But it is not working on that.

Answer (score 2):

better to use AutoComplete Control of AjaxToolkit. It workes similar as you are trying. Please check out the demo here: [AutoComplete Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)

```
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
runat="server" 
ID="autoComplete1" 
TargetControlID="myTextBox"
ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx"
MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
CompletionInterval="1000"
EnableCaching="true"
CompletionSetCount="20" 
CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement" 
CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem" 
CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"
DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true">
    <Animations>
        <OnShow> ... </OnShow>
        <OnHide> ... </OnHide>
    </Animations>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default asp.net textbox is not able to do that.

Try reading up about JQuery, ajax and autocomplete. 
You can use something like: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-jQuery-AutoComplete-Plugin-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
  TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(event,'" + Button1.ClientID + "')");
```

The code behind generates the following code:

```
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" onkeypress="return clickButton(event,'Button1')"  />
```

This causes web control Button1 to be clicked when the enter key is hit inside TextBox1.
You can customize this Example for your need.